# Linux Random Number Generator failed to capture the Java Robot Keyboard and Mouse Actions. How to solve it?

Tags: java, linux, random, simulation

I am using the Java Robot to simulate Keyboard and mouse movement every 5 minutes. And I want to see how Linux random number generator takes the movement as user input random seed. Surprisingly, the Java robot works well on my Linux 2.6.32 running on a Virtual Machine, but nothing captured on Linux 2.6.32 running on a standalone machine.

Is it because the standalone machine is somehow taking user input on a lower hardware level? How to simulate keyboard and mouse movement on a standalone Linux machine?

Comment: If you need really random numbers you could buy (or use) a random number generator device.

Comment: And you could upgrade your kernel. [Current one](http://kernel.org/) is 3.12

Comment: What would be the sense of using program generated events as input source for randomness?

Comment: It is a long run testing, so need to automate and simulate the user input.